# Point and click interface on Enterprise guide is missing

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, sas

I'm a newbie. 
I've used SAS Enterprise Guide on machines at school. I installed it on my own machine and for some reason do not have the point and click interface, or any of it's menus (Describe/Analyze/etc). Can someone tell me how to rectify this situation? I can write code in the code window, but the problem is that as a newbie, I can't write code, or at least not much past my libref statement! Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
LA,

Comment: Are you successfully connecting to a server?  How are you licensed - are you using an educational copy for example (connecting to SAS's cloud) or a full copy with its own local server?

Comment: I have installed a full copy and am using my machine as local server.